# Google Compute Engine healthcheck initial delay appears to be ignored

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

In our project, we have a gRPC healthcheck configured for a Google Compute Engine instance group. The configuration is similar to as follows:

```
# ...


resource "google_compute_health_check" "instances_health_check" {
  name = "instances-health-check"

  timeout_sec = 5
  check_interval_sec = 10

  grpc_health_check {
    port = "8087"
  }
}

# Generates instance group for each GCP zone in `local.zone_to_region`.
resource "google_compute_instance_group_manager" "instances" {
  for_each = local.zone_to_region

  base_instance_name = "instance-${each.key}"
  name = "group-${each.key}"
  target_pools = []
  target_size = 0
  wait_for_instances = false
  zone = each.key

  version {
    instance_template = module.instance_templates[each.value[0]].template.self_link
  }

  auto_healing_policies {
    health_check = google_compute_health_check.processor_health_check.id
    initial_delay_sec = 600
  }
}

# ...
```

When a new instance is spun up, it receives its first healthcheck request in 1-2 minutes after start, which is not enough for our app to become operational. The configured `initial_delay_sec` seems to be ignored.

This leads to multiple undesirable warnings emitted to our logs. The warnings have this format:

```
{
    "@type":"type.googleapis.com/compute.InstanceGroupManagerEvent",
    "instanceHealthStateChange":{
        detailedHealthState: "UNHEALTHY",
        // ...
        previousDetailedHealthState: "UNKNOWN"

    }
}
```

Any way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `initial_delay` parameter is a configuration of MIG (Instance Group Manager) autohealing, and not the healthcheck itself.

The way it works is that

1. The instance starts being probed almost immediately after it is created by the MIG. You need to make sure that your health check endpoint does not return success until your application is ready.
2. The MIG uses the health results to auto-heal the instances if it is not healthy. And here the `initial_delay` parameter comes into play: unhealthy results will be ignored for this period. After that if the VM is still unhealthy, it will be repaired (i.e. recreated).

Comment: Thanks! I got confused by this particular doc: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/high-availability-autohealing#set_up_the_web_service
Phrasing under point 2 makes it seem like healthchecks themselves are delayed: `Note: Initial delay indicates how long to wait before sending the first health check...`

Comment: @DmitryKuzmin Thanks for the link, I will try to get it corrected.

Answer (score 1):

As the accepted answer states, it is particularly confusing, especially since every other cloud provider respects initial delays/grace periods.

For this reason, we have escalated this to a feature request to have the ability to specify this:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/239964145